# Why I need to produce a class from MainForm?

Tags: c#, oop

I am sorry if I am asking something stupid but I am completely a newbie in C# and ASP.NET. I am trying to analyze a Windows Forms App project and I saw the code I gave below.

```
namespace blabla
{
    public partial class Mainform : Form
    {
        public static MainForm form; // I don't understand this line why be used
        public MainForm()
        {
           form = this;
           initializeComponent();  
        }
     ....
    }
}
```

My question is why this declaration is used
`public static MainForm form;`
 it produce a object from MainForm and then it attach the form with "form" variable via the code below;
`form = this;`

and in another class they used the code below
`MainForm.form.Text = "blablabla"`

I can understand what they do but I don't understand the logic why they use this way and what is this line

`MainForm.form.Text = "blablabla"`
 when I tried this line in another project, it writes the strings to the title of window.

Please, can you explain the logic behind the code?
Thank you,
Regards.

Comment: Presumably it's a hacky way of referencing the form from elsewhere. It's not good because if you create two instances of the form, the second one will replace the first in the variable.

Comment: *"I am completely a newbie"* - learn about classes, fields, properties, static/instance members, singletons. Then you should be able to understand `MainForm.form.Text = "blablabla"` and ask good tittled questions. Given code tell us something not nice about author.

Comment: thanks for your help. I got the idea. also, thanks for recommendations

Comment: In C# everything is an object and objects have a class that tells what you can do with the object. The static class MainForm is the starting point where your program starts running. There a re some good video courses that teach you the basics of programming in C#, Choose one that starts learning how to create console applications.if you want tips on some good courses, send me a PM.